# maximum number of results in foursquare api?

Tags: javascript, foursquare

i am using foursquare venues search API to get search results using javascript.

But I only get 50 results.

How do I get more than 50 results (say, around 100 or 200)?

used api:
https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search?query=Hotels&ll=40.70590473669712,-73.9780035&limit=50&radius=3200&client_id=clinetid&client_secret=clientsecret

Comment: i add the api what i use.

Comment: if i use 'nearby point' means, any possibility to get duplicate results?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Foursquare's API has a 50 result limit, *however*, you can get more results that may overlap by using a nearby point, like this:

```
https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search?ll=100.100,-30.010&limit=50
https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search?ll=100.110,-30.110&limit=50
```

Comment: if i use 'nearby point' means, any possibility to get duplicate results?

Comment: @user1954835 It's pretty likely that you'll get duplicated results, yeah. Just filter them out and keep changing the point by a tiny margin till you have an arbitrary number of unique results.

Answer (score 0):

You can tell the Foursquare API to return more results (up to 500) via the `limit` parameter, as [described here.](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/venues/herenow)

Comment: He's using the `search` API from venues, and that has a limit of 50, as described [here](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/venues/search)

Comment: how i change my api using venues herenow to 500 results

Comment: Ah yes. I don't know how to bypass that. :|